# SQL Server User Logins

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure

This has probably been asked before but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated!

I'm using an Azure SQL server and want to have user logins from any IP. However, the Azure firewall (or any SQL server I think?) will only allow users to connect to the server/make database queries within a range of IP addresses. How can I programmatically allow any user to signup via my program with an arbitrary IP add a row to my database table?

```
string sqlconnstring = "X";
using(SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection(sqlconnstring)){ // <--error
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We too use SQL AZURE and well, from what I know about it this will not be possible without some work on your side and from my point a view some security holes.  In order to add a IP to the firewall you need a connection to the [database already](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270017.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Follow that to get that one figured out.  The issue will be is that somehow you will need to open some kind of endpoint that will allow only authenticated people to add IPs to the firewall, that is the real issue here and something I would think you would want to consider long and hard about doing before you do.

From my perspective you should create a API for your application and use that. You could use a [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779(v=VS.110).aspx) or something else that meets your needs, but what you are asking for is something I would not recommend.

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare that users need to have direct access to a database. Instead you should define a WCF service and expose the data through predefined data contracts and service contracts. However if you absolutely need to let users access it, then install a local SQL Server instance on your own server, and add the Azure connection as a linked server. Your users can connect to your server, and your server queries azure.

http://asadkhan1973.blogspot.ca/2012/09/add-sql-azure-as-linked-server.html

You could also just install a proxy on your server to let users connect to Azure through it.

Comment: I hope im not confusing what you're saying. However, what I want to do is allow users to sign in using a simple GUI and afterwards return their profile information on a screen. But I don't see how to submit a query to obtain their information without having their IP in the azure firewall because they need an authorized connection string to the database in order to obtain their respective info. I don't want them to have access to my azure portal.

Comment: Maybe a better question would help emphasize the source of my confusion- and please bear in mind im new to SQL. What does adding an IP into the Azure firewall permit? Can I execute SQL queries to my azure server via a button click if my program is on someone else's machine?

Comment: So, in this case, you need to design a WCF web service that you will host on your own server, that client applications will connect to, that exposes a .GetProfile() method, that in turn queries your database. That way the client app connects only to your service, and never the database.